# Cannot killed spawned Ender Dragon with sword in 1.10.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

He doesn't move at all and I can't hit him, just random particles appear. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/kill` command to delete the ender dragon, provided you do not use a radius:

```
/kill @e[type=EnderDragon,c=1]
```

---

When you summon an ender dragon with the following command:

```
/summon EnderDragon
```

The `DragonPhase` value defaults to 10, which stands for "hovering". During this phase, its `Motion` values are locked to "NaN", which prevents you from attacking it with a sword because that relies on its position, which has been corrupted by invalid values. It is for the same reason you cannot use a radius to select it.

If you want to be able to attack the previously-summoned dragon, you will need to both change its `DragonPhase` value to something else, as well as reset its `Motion` (which is as simple as providing an empty list):

```
/entitydata @e[type=EnderDragon,c=1] {DragonPhase:0,Motion:[]}
```

The dragon will not move from its position until you relog, but you can still hit it.

Alternatively, you can summon it with a different phase, though it will immediately fly to (0,0,0):

```
/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {DragonPhase:0}
```